# Registering Custom Protocol for Windows Phone 8 App WebBrowser Control

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone-8

I'm searching for a way to register a custom protocol for Windows Phone 8. I tried to register a custom protocol with `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("xxx://", this)` but this will not work for the `WebBrowser` control. Since our protocol scheme is no valid uri the app will just crash if it try to navigate (via location.url='xxx://this-is-no-valid-uri').

I hope anyone can spread light into the darkness ;)

EDIT: [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7499473/crashing.zip) is my test project. I think this is a major bug because you can force every app to crash with just a simple JavaScript statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a Solution for my Problem, you need to register a own UriParser.

**My UriParser:**

```
public class MyUriParser : UriParser
{
    public MyUriParser()
    {

    }

    protected override string GetComponents(Uri uri, UriComponents components, UriFormat format)
    {
        return "";
    }
    protected override bool IsWellFormedOriginalString(Uri uri)
    {
        return true;
    }
    protected override void InitializeAndValidate(Uri uri, out UriFormatException parsingError)
    {
        parsingError = null;
    }
    protected override bool IsBaseOf(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri)
    {
        return false;
    }
    protected override string Resolve(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri, out UriFormatException parsingError)
    {
        parsingError = null;
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Registered via:**

```
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme(SCHEMENAME_0))
    UriParser.Register(new MyUriParser(), SCHEMENAME_0, 80);
```

Comment: Now any click on a link with your own protocol (SCHEMENAME_0) will be passed through the WebBrowser in the navigating event.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work, is there anything other than these two steps that you took to get a custom protocol firing the navigating event?

Comment: No just those two steps. Maybe its not clear that SCHEMENAME_0 is just the name like "test", the Uri passed thru the eventargs would throw everywhere an exception except on OriginalString Property (if i remember right) those OriginalString would than be something like: "test://func(call)".

Answer (score 4):

Recently i had to create a [custom uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_LaunchingaURIusingProximity) scheme,and that was pretty easy
in your WMAppManifest add:

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="XXXX" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

this is stands after `Tokens`

than in your App.cs file you redirect to the class which is responsible for the navigation

```
RootFrame.UriMapper = new CustomUriMapper();
```

for example

```
class CustomUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    private string tempUri;
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

        if (tempUri.Contains("XXXX"))
        {
         return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?parameter=XXXX", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else
            {
                return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }           
    }
}
```

i hope i helped

EDIT

i have create a small project, and i'm sure it works, please try this

```
            string url = "xxxx:";
            WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
            browser.URL = url;
            browser.Show();
```

Comment: since we got no valid uri from location.url ="xxx://NOTVALIDURI" this will not work as Uri will throw the cannot parse url exception...

Comment: can you try it like this :)

Comment: No this is not working as i said the url is NOT a valid uri. It is impossible to instanciate a class Uri with a malformed url. `location.href = 'slitte://Showcaptionbutton="Info", openInfos()';` inside a webpage (javascript) WILL crash the running app. 

Here is my test project; [click](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7499473/crashing.zip)

Comment: I was talking about the WebBrowser control inside my app not the standalone IE on the phone.

Comment: it's working with webbrowser control too, looked `private void InitializePhoneApplication()`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_LaunchingaURIusingProximity

Comment: just checkout the test project i provided. it is not working.

Comment: since all provided functions to do any URI interaction is based on the class Uri not a single solution will work because the url is NOT uri conform. the class Uri is not able to parse this kind of url and just throws an exception. and this happens inside the WebBrowser control after executing javascript. it is also possible to crash the app if you click a malformed `<a href="test://i m invalid test()"> LINK </a>` in the WebBrowser control. Microsoft have to fix this issue. This is a major bug.

Comment: sorry bro,i really wanted to help